# javaScript to get around background attachment: fixed on mobile

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

I am building a page that has the following structure:

```
<div class="img1"></div>
<div class="info"></div>
<div class="img2"></div>
<div class="info"></div>
<div class="img3"></div>
```

The img1/2/3 divs have a background image in fixed background-attachment position and set to a fixed height, and the info divs have solid background color with a fixed height also.  This gives a cool scroll effect.  As I have figured out, mobile does not support this.  I have been trying to figure out a solution to this.  I have seen a couple of attempts at solutions using js and one using CSS on here.  None seem to be accurate.  Anyone have a good solution?  If I had to choose I would prefer it look better on iOS for the time being.

Comment: Give more details. Add maybe fiddle. What mobile doesn't support?

Comment: Mobile doesn't support the background-attachment: fixed; attribute.  Primarily because it kills scrolling functionality.  Seems to be a popular problem, but have not seen anything as of late posted about it regarding solutions and ways to get around it and get the same scrolling effect.

Comment: Can you please create fiddle? If u will check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment you will see mobile support. It looks like something different is not working on mobile